# Missing type System.Windows.Automation.Peers.FrameworkElementAutomationPeer in module System.Windows.dll

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-8

Cannot find type System.Windows.Automation.Peers.FrameworkElementAutomationPeer in module System.Windows.dll.

How to resolve this error? What namespace am I missing?

Comment: is `PesentationFramework.dll` referenced in your app? `using System.Windows.Automation.Peers;` should work fine. MSDN:http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.automation.peers.frameworkelementautomationpeer(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 2):

According to MSDN the `System.Windows.Automation.Peers` namespace resides in `PresentationFramework.dll`

is PresentationFramework.dll referenced in your app?

MSDN: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.automation.peers.frameworkelementautomationpeer(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: I wasn't even using System.Windows.Automation.Peers in anyway but then I got rid of the error by removing this reference which I wasn't using either: Microsoft.Phone.Contrp;s.Maps.dll
But now that I know of the namespace, I can use it for laters incase the error pops up again. So thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Removed Microsoft.Phone.Controls.Maps.dll from the reference.